# Confused on the difference between One, and One and Only One in ERDs

Tags: data-modeling, entity-relationship, cardinality, erd

Sorry for the links I'm new! I'm confused on the difference between one and one and only one and where they would be used. I just started the class so I apologize if my diagram is wrong as well.

[Hospital Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPUww.jpg)

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQVdJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but I think this is good answer for you from Wiki: "[The inner component of the notation represents the minimum, and the outer component represents the maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Crow%27s_foot_notation)"

And more visualize: https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/crow-s-foot-notation/

So in your case: "Any patient who is admitted must have **exactly one** admitting physician" need an **One and only one** relationship. I think your diagram is alright. Keep going on

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit of research and it seems like there is no difference between them however as computer scientists we like to make things clear and unambiguous - thus double dash was introduced.

Essentially double dash removes ambiguity but means the same thing!